# system call tracing using ptrace

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, ptrace

I wrote a program to list all the system calls executed by a command (say /bin/ls). Now what I am trying to do is find all the system call arguments, environment variables, command line arguments that may be passed to it

> Example: If I open a file. The system call sys_access will open the file right ? But how to get these values? 
>  Want to do this for  system calls like open, read, write, close.

As per my study these must be in the registers (ebx - edx) If so what does these register values signify?
I got this [link](http://bluemaster.iu.hio.no/edu/dark/lin-asm/syscalls.html).
 But I really couldn't get much from there. Also any further references for this would be much helpful.

Comment: Does this help: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/syscalls.h

Comment: @dbrank0: Thanks a lot. It indeed is of help. But I have got one more question. 
The output of my earlier program is like this
`code`SYSCALL  33:         ebx :004c48de ecx:  00000000 edx: 004c8ff4 /access
RETURN  33: fffffffe

The values in this are in hex. So how do I make sense out of it? Im am a noob programmer. Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: filename is stored at 0x4c48de, mode is 0 (see mode flag defines), edx is not relevant and contains something undefined, and return value is -2 (it's complaining about read-only filesystem).

Comment: @dbrank0: thanks a lot for your help. Yeah i was running under normal user. Before was root. How can I mark this question solved :D
No answers. :D lol.

Comment: @dbrank0 should add an answer since he helped you solve the problem.

Comment: `strace` is doing exactly what you want. You could use it, or study its source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Revised form of comments above (so you can accept it)):

Detailed syscall parameters can be looked up in Linux kernel header [syscalls.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/syscalls.h). 
In above case, as sys_access (#33 on x86) has only two parameters:

- first is the pointer to filename, so your file name was stored at address 0x4c4d8e
- Second parameter is file mode (see mode flag defines)
- as there is no third parameter to this syscall, edx is not relevant and contains some undefined value

Return value of this syscall is -2 (ENOENT, defined in [errno-base.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h)), which signifies error (no such file or directory).

Also note (see Basile's comment above) that you are duplicating the functionality of [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) utility.

Comment: thanks again. I was trying to do it in ptrace so I can learn it. Bt isnt ptrace more friendly to use in C? I mean the peekuser, getregs and all are fun. :D

Comment: It's fun provided your schedule allows playing with it. :)